# Can't get firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() from a second activity (or fragments)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I need to get

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()
```

from a second activity "DetailActivity" but i've got a Null pointer :
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference

I can access it from the "MainActivity" but not from my bottomnavigationview fragments nor from the second activity "DetailActivity"

here is my code :

Connexion activity

```
public class ConnexionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBinding = ActivityConnexionBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(mBinding.getRoot());
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        setGoogleSignIn();
    }

    //////////////////////GOOGLE LOGIN
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // GOOGLE
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> mAccountTask = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = mAccountTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
                FirebaseAuthWithGoogleAccount(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OnClick: ERROR ACTIVITY RESULT NOT OK");

        }
        // FACEBOOK
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    private void FirebaseAuthWithGoogleAccount(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseauthwithgoogleaccount: begin firebase auth with google account");
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "OnSuccess: Logged in");
                        // Get logged in user
                        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                        // Get user info
                        String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
                        String email = firebaseUser.getEmail();
                        Log.d(TAG, "OnSuccess: Email" + email);
                        Log.d(TAG, "OnSuccess: uid" + uid);
                        // Check if user is new or existing
                        if (Objects.requireNonNull(authResult.getAdditionalUserInfo()).isNewUser()) {
                            // User is new account created
                            Log.d(TAG, "OnSuccess: Account created...\n" + email);
                            Toast.makeText(ConnexionActivity.this, "Account created...\n" + email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // Existing user logged in
                            Log.d(TAG, "OnSuccess: Existing user... \n" + email);
                            Toast.makeText(ConnexionActivity.this, "Existing user...\n" + email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // Start MainActivity
                        startActivity(new Intent(ConnexionActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "OnFailure: Loggin failed" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }

    private void setGoogleSignIn() {
        // Configure google sign in
        GoogleSignInOptions mGoogleSignInOption = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.requestidtoken))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, mGoogleSignInOption);

        // Init firebase auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }
    //////////////////////GOOGLE END

    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                //Start main activity
                startActivity(new Intent(ConnexionActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                Toast.makeText(ConnexionActivity.this,
                        "You successfully signed-in ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
//    @Override
//    protected void onDestroy() {
//
//        // FIREBASE LOGOUT
//        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
//        // GOOGLE LOGOUT
//        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.
//                Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).
//                build();
//
//        GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(ConnexionActivity.this, gso);
//        googleSignInClient.signOut();
//        // FACBOOK LOGOUT
//        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
//        super.onDestroy();
//    }
```

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = mBinding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser == null){
            reload();
        }
    }

    // restart connexion activity if the user isn't connected
    private void reload(){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ConnexionActivity.class));
            finish();
    }

    private void setBottomNavigationView(){
        mBinding.bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(mBinding.fragmentContainer.getId(), new MapFragment()).commit();
    }

    private final BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = item -> {

        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == R.id.map_view) {
            selectedFragment = new MapFragment();
        } else if (itemId == R.id.list_view) {
            selectedFragment = new ListViewFragment();
        } else if (itemId == R.id.workmates) {
                selectedFragment = new WorkmatesFragment();
        }
        if (selectedFragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();
        }
        return true;
    };
```

The fragment adapter where i launch the DetailActivity :

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Result restaurant = mRestaurants.get(position);
        ((ListViewViewHolder) holder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Context context = view.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("idrestaurant", restaurant.getPlaceId());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

DetailActivty :

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBinding = ActivityDetailBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = mBinding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);
    }
    private void setClickChosenRestaurantButton(){
        mBinding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
                        Map<String, Object> chosenRestaurant = new HashMap<>();
                        chosenRestaurant.put("restaurantChosen", getRestaurantId());
                        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                        DocumentReference docRef = UserCallData.getAllUsers().getFirestore().collection("users").document(firebaseUser.getUid());
                        docRef.set(chosenRestaurant, SetOptions.merge()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                Log.d("123", "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.d("123", "Error writing document", e);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("123", "pb with firebaseauth!");
                    }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

D/123: pb with firebaseauth!

To be honest i do not understand in detail the behavior of the Firebase auth system that's why i'm stuck here.

Any idea?

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **600** (six hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, you are right i deleted useless parts thank you for the tip !

Comment: Are you sure the user is authenticated when you call `.getUid()`? Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help.

Comment: When i'm in my MainActivity i can perfectly access to FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() but when i'm in a fragment or another activity it seems that user isn't authenticated and i can not access to getCurrentUser() anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it doesn't work :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    // FIREBASE LOGOUT
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    // GOOGLE LOGOUT
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.
            Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).
            build();

    GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(ConnexionActivity.this, gso);
    googleSignInClient.signOut();
    // FACBOOK LOGOUT
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

In my ConnectionActivity

This disconnected my FirebaseUser when i destroyed ConnexionActivity after each connexion of the user.

I switch it to my MainActivity which isn't destroyed until the app crash or the user forces it to close.